# Generate table creation scripts from Oracle Database 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

A table in Oracle Database 11g contains the sequences and triggers if we are to use auto-increment fields.

I'm using the Oracle SQL Developer and couldn't find a solid way to create a consolidated table creation script.

Is it possible to create a consolidated DDL script with the below artefacts for a given table :

1. Table creation
2. Sequences
3. Triggers
4. Foreign keys
5. Primary keys

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [MRE] with: an example table; your expected output for that example; whether you want to create the table from scratch or if you want to reverse engineer the DDL from an existing implementation; and a definition of what you mean by "consolidated DDL script" (Do you mean a single DDL statement or do you mean several statements? In the latter case, why not use `CREATE SEQUENCE ...`, `CREATE TABLE ...` , `ALTER TABLE ... ADD CONSTRAINT ...` then `CREATE TRIGGER ...`?).

Answer (score 1):

It is the `DBMS_METADATA` built-in package we use for such a purpose and its `GET_DDL` function.

More info in [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e40758/d_metada.htm#ARPLS026).

Quite a few examples on [Oracle-base](https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/dbms_metadata) site (scroll down, to the bottom of the page).

For a single table (which is what you asked), you'd run e.g.

```
select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE', 'EMP', 'SCOTT') from dual;
```

Comment: This doesn't include associated sequences and triggers. Any approach to do that?

Comment: What is "this"? DBMS_METADATA package contains *everything*. Did you read documentation about it? You might be intersted in GET_DEPENDENT_DDL function.

Comment: In 11g, sequences and tables have no relationship in the DB. It is purely user code that associates the two together. That said, usually you have a sequence named similarly to the primary key column, if that’s how you’ve done it for your application schema then you can easily code something to look up the likely sequence name and grab the DDL with dbms_metadata.